# Problema al imprimir y redireccionar jquery firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugin

Buenas noches, escribo en esta oportunidad porque estoy intentando imprimir un `div` y luego que me redireccione a la página principal, pero el problema que presenta es que no me redirecciona, lo intente en `firefox` y me pasa eso, es como si solo hiciera una acción imprimir nada más, como podría hacer para que me funcione?

Este es el código que estoy utilizando, alguna idea para solucionar este problema:

```
$(document).on('ready',function (e){
$(".testbutton").click(function () {
    $("div#myPrintArea").printArea();
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $(location).attr('href','/inicio/'); 
    },2000);
});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola utiliza algunas de las siguientes alternativas para redireccionar, ambas son validas.

```
window.location.replace('/inicio/');
```

ó

```
window.location.href = '/inicio/';
```

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por responderme, me funciono la solución de Ricardo y Gustavo, la probe y me redirecciona bien.

Answer (score 1):

No es necesario utilizar jQuery para envolver a `location`. Para realizar una redirección, puedes hacerlo mediante el método `replace` o simplemente sobreescribiendo la propiedad `href`:

```
location.relace('/inicio');
```

También puedes hacerlo mediante `assign`:

```
location.assign('/inicio/');
```

La diferente entre `replace` y `assign` es que el primero reemplaza en el historial la entrada actual, mientras que `assign` crea una nueva.

Comment: **Claro que es posible manejar**  `location` con `Jquery`, creo que lo correcto sería decir que **no es necesario usar Jquery para esto.**

Comment: Estás en lo cierto. Tenía entendido que no era posible (al no ser un elemento propiamente dicho, no lo intenté jamás porque no lo vi relevante), pero veo que sí. Gracias por la correción.

Answer (score -1):

Sino me equivoco el $location debe ser una direccion exacta, no una carpeta

```
$(document).on('ready',function (e){
$(".testbutton").click(function () {
    $("div#myPrintArea").printArea();
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $(location).attr('href','/inicio/index.php'); 
    },2000);
});
});
```

Comment: No necesariamente , una carpeta también es considerada una location.

Comment: @Dev.Joel mmm ya. no sabia eso :)

Comment: No necesariamente, si no pasas el archivo por defecto los servidores apache estan configurados para tomar el index.php a menos que se haya cambiado, tambien puede ser que las url se esten sobreescribiendo usando un truco con el archivo `.htaccess` para tener url bonitas.